# Doing a turntable camera animation on a world matrix rather than view matrix

Tags: opengl, camera, matrix

I have a camera class that contains a 4x4 view matrix as a member variable. Most of my camera controls work fine when doing them directly on the view matrix. In an attempt to unify all of my scene objects I want to do all of these transformations on the local matrix.

I plan on ultimately switching to a model with scale, position and rotation stored separately but that isn't the question at the moment.

Here my question again in a (hopefully more clear way):

I want to perform a turn table animation on a camera (rotation around an arbitrary point)
I have working code for doing it directly on the view matrix.
Also very important, the rotation must be around a set up axis (in my case +Y).

How can I achieve the same affect by transforming the local matrix directly?

**Working turn table control directly on view matrix**

```
// dX and dY are mouse deltas for the current frame
Vector3 position = viewMatrix.getPosition();
Vector3 forward = viewMatrix.getForward();
Vector3 right = viewMatrix.getRight();

// rotate around the focal point in front of us
Vector3 rotationPoint = position + forward * focalPoint;

Matrix4 rot;
rot.translate(rotationPoint);
rot.rotate(-dY, right);
rot.rotate(-dX, Vector3::Y_AXIS);
rot.translate(-rotationPoint);

viewMatrix = viewMatrix * rot;
```

**Attempt to make it work on the local matrix:**

```
// dX and dY are mouse deltas for the current frame
Vector3 position = localMatrix.getPosition();
Vector3 forward = localMatrix.getForward();
Vector3 right = localMatrix.getRight();

// rotate around the focal point in front of us
Vector3 rotationPoint = position + forward * focalPoint;

Matrix4 rot;
rot.translate(-rotationPoint);
rot.rotate(dX, Vector3::Y_AXIS);
rot.rotate(dY, right);
rot.translate(rotationPoint);

localMatrix = localMatrix * rot;
```

What happens: The animation is wonky, the pivot point seem to move while I rotate and the camera slowly drifts away.

Additional information:

Why do I need that?
I want to be able to transform any scene object the same way. I might want to rotate a mesh around a point like I do the camera.

Is it easier to achieve what I want with a scale/position/rotation model?
Even if it is I'm still interested on where I'm making a mistake here.

I will edit this post in the morning if there are any uncertain parts.

**------------------------------------------------------**

**Edit:**

I tried to rephrase my problem a bit I will leave the initial post for now, I hope I am more clear in this second attempt.

My Problem: I have working code for controlling a cameras view matrix and orbiting around a point in space.

Here is said code:

```
// get position and look at, look up and look right directions for the view matrix
Vector3 pos, la, lu, lr;
viewMatrix.lookAt(&pos, &la, &lu, &lr);

// rotate around point 5 units in front of us
Vector3 rotationPoint = pos+ la * 5; 

Matrix4 rot;
rot.translate(rotationPoint);
rot.rotate(-dY, lr);
rot.rotate(-dX, Vector3(0,1,0));
rot.translate(-rotationPoint);
viewMatrix *= rot;
```

here is the code for the lookAt function used above:
It will retrieve you the position and forward, right, up directions from a VIEW matrix.

```
void Matrix4::lookAt(Vector3* eye, Vector3* at, Vector3* up, Vector3* ri)
{  
    Matrix3 invRot(_m);               // get the current view matrix
    invRot.translation(0,0,0);          // remove the translation
    invRot.transpose();                 // transpose it to get inverse rot.
    eye->set(invRot.multVec(-translation())); // setMatrix eye
    ri->set( _m[0], _m[4], _m[8]);            // normalized look right vector
    up->set( _m[1], _m[5], _m[9]);            // normalized look up vector
    at->set(-_m[2],-_m[6],-_m[10]);           // normalized look at vector
}
```

Note: the matrices are column major.

The code above works, the camera orbits an object around the world Y axis perfeclty.
What I want to do: I want this same behaviour, but on a cube or other mesh! So I obviously don't need to do it on the view matrix then, since the transformation of that cube uses a world matrix. Now I could of course use the above and just invert it, but that is kind of cheating.

Here is my attempt to make the above work on a world space matrix:

```
// get the position and the three axis directions for the world matrix
Vector3 pos, la, lu, lr;
pos = worldMatrix.translation();
la.set(-worldMatrix.m(8), -worldMatrix.m(9), -worldMatrix.m(10));
lr.set(worldMatrix.m(0), worldMatrix.m(1), worldMatrix.m(2));
lu.set(worldMatrix.m(4), worldMatrix.m(5), worldMatrix.m(6));


Vector3 rotationPoint = pos + la * 5;

Matrix4 rot;
rot.translate(-rotationPoint);
rot.rotate(dX, Vector3(0,1,0));
rot.rotate(dY, lr);
rot.translate(rotationPoint);

worldMatrix *= rot;
```

The matrix is still column major. The retrieved position, look at, look right and look up vectors are correct. But when I print out the rotationPoint it moves. So the question is as simple as: Why does the above world matrix code not rotate my cube around the Y and look right axis around 'rotationPoint'?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are dealing with additive operations (i.e. rotation translation order is important). Generally you would want to update your Camera matrix in this order:

1. Take identity matrix.
2. Translate to `FocalPoint`
3. Rotate to look in to the right direction
4. Translate away from the `FocalPoint` by the `DistanceFromFocal`

Same works with any Object that you want to place instead of Camera.

If above approach works for the Camera, but not for the Object, then there's a bug in your code somewhere

Comment: Yes I get that part. It is working in my first code example (which uses a view matrix). The is that I can't do the same thing on a world space matrix! The second code example is me trying to do it but the rotations are wrong and the rotation point changes.

Comment: So .. you have a working code for a proper turntable (Camera orbiting Objects). Now you want to redo it into static Camera looking at rotating World? This kind of defeats the point of having a Camera, don't you think? ;)

Comment: I don't know if you missed it in my post or if I was unclear about it. But the reason I want to do the same in world space is because I want to apply this orbiting animation to a cube or other mesh. If I was to reuse my 'working' code I would have to do the rotation on a view matrix and then invert it to use that matrix as the model matrix for said cube. This seems unnecessary since I could just transform the model matrix (world matrix) directly.

Comment: I tried to redo my post in an edit but left the original post up for now. Maybe you understand what I mean if you read the second try.

Comment: @derkie: Answer updated

Comment: Ok thanks for your help so far. I setup a minimal test case to compare view vs world transform on a cube. I'll report back in a few days when I had the time to check it out.